# resharper or VS hotkey to switch places two parameters, is there such a thing?

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, resharper, hotkeys

it something like this `method(a,b);` and you hit some hotkey and you get `method(b,a);`
is there such thing ?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can try

> Ctrl+Shift+Alt+left arrow/right arrow

.

Found under

> Resharper->Code->Move Left or Move
>   Right

.

Comment: NOTE: this is NOT a refactoring, meaning it will NOT change any callers. It is simply a way to move the text around. If you truly want to refactor (reorder all callers appropriately), use Change Signature, as Sam Holder suggests.

Comment: Awesome.  Great for fixing (other people's of course) Assert.AreEqual() mistakes.

Comment: Yeah. Other people. Ahem. :)

Answer (score 7):

I don't know if there is a hot key that does just that, but using Resharper you can refactor->change signature, and then reorder the parameters.

The default hot key for change signature is Ctrl-F6

Comment: Tools=>options=>keyboard - should be possible to set hotkey.

Comment: In R# 8, the hotkey is CTRL+R, S

Answer (score 0):

I know [Refactor pro](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/Visual_Studio_Add-in/Refactoring/) does this - it is called the "Reorder Parameters" refactoring.

Looks like VS 10 also has this [built in](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5ss5z206%28VS.100%29.aspx).

And ReSharper calles it [Change Signature](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/documentation/help20/Refactoring/changesignature.html).

Comment: and msvs2005 though probably not express version

Answer (score 0):

In VS >= 2005 Ctrl-R, O is default for inbuilt reorder parameters I think - or right click and chose refactor menu. I dont think this is available on express of course.